# two types of input from one string

Tags: python

i am asking the user to input a number as well as if they think their number plus a random integer will be odd or even in the same line but cant get it to work.
I wrote

```
user, num = input('Enter a number 1-10: ' and '\n odd or even?').split()
```

Only the 2nd string is asked (odd or even?) when i run the program.

i want it to be formatted as
Enter a number 1-10: \n
odd or even?

How do I take two different types of inputs using one line of code. i want the input from
'Enter a number: '
to be an int and i want the input from
'odd or even' to be a str

Comment: Remove the `and` and use a single string.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can simply use two lines of input. something like this:

```
num = int(input('Enter your number: '))
state = input('Odd or Even?')
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove and it will work

```py
>>> user, num = input('Enter a number 1-10:  odd or even? ').split()
Enter a number 1-10:  odd or even?10 3
>>> user
'10'
>>> num
'3'
>>>
```

`input()` outputs strings. You may have to convert it to int using `int(num)`.

Comment: thank you but that doesn't help

Comment: that just puts both inputs on one line i want it to be formatted as                                                  Enter a number 1-10: 1                                                                                                                       odd or even? odd

Comment: this is the only answer that points out that the `and` is the issue.

Comment: @jack then you have to break the input into 2 lines

Answer (score -2):

try this line:

```
user, num = input('Enter a number 1-10:' + '\nodd or even?\n').split()
```